# JavaScript RegEx zero or one string in bracets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a given string (let it be 'start') with possible presence of a special ending or without it. The ending could be '(a)' or '(b)' or '(c)', I mean one of letters a, b or c in braces. If there is no braces or just one brace or they are in the wrong order than there should be no match. Broke my head trying to make appropriate RegEx.
So full list of possible matches:

```
start
start(a)
start(b)
start(c)
```

Any other input should produce no match.

Comment: and you have tried what? this seems pretty easy

Comment: Really, just single letters `a`, `b`, and `c`? What was your exact problem(s)? *Broke my head trying to make appropriate RegEx* is not a (good) problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is : `^start(\([abc]\))?$`

for better reading you can go to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3qPaCb/1)

here it is what it does : 
[image]

Comment: where did you get this picture ?

Comment: [regexper.com](https://regexper.com/) is a must to understand regexes ;)

Answer (score -1):

If either `(a)` or `(b)` or `(c)` are valid you can use this

`\([abc]\)`

[Check this out](http://regexr.com/3eoob)

Comment: either `(a|b|c)` or `[abc]`

Comment: [a|b|c] [] define a set caractere no need of pipe "|"